# Requirement Error while setting up PgAdmin4

Tags: python, pip, apache-age

I'm facing an issue while trying to install dependencies from a *[requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506852/what-is-the-requirements-txt-what-should-be-in-it)* file using the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command. Here's what I've done:

- I have a requirements.txt file in my project directory.
- I navigated to the project directory in my terminal.
- I ran the command pip install -r requirements.txt.error while setting up pgAdmin4.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/fahad/work/pgadmin4/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/fahad/work/pgadmin4/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_
```

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please show a [**complete**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting all the way to the end. What you have shown is obviously not complete; it cuts off in the middle of a stack trace.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [Apache AGE](https://age.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, the command `krb5-config` that is required as a build dependency for one of the packages in your `requirements.txt` file is missing.
You should update your pip and setup tools and then install `krb5-config` by running;

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

`sudo apt-get install krb5-config`

Answer (score 0):

> /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found

The above cause of error means the package with that config file is missing. To install, simply run `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev`.

Prior to installation of `libkrb5-dev`, ensure the right version of Python required for AGE is installed and also update/upgrade `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of it happens on some other OS (the package required names)

- Centos/Fedora: `krb5-devel`
- MacOS: `krb5`