# Problems creating a Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a Python package with the following structure:

```
VisionPy/
│   __init__.py
│   main.py
│   plugin_interface.py
│   README.md
│
├── controllers/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── imagecontroller.py
│   ├── volumecontroller.py
│
├── models/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── imagemodel.py
│   ├── volumemodel.py
│
├── plugins/
│   ├── CScan/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── NDEToolkit.py
│   │   ├── plugin.py
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│
├── ui/
│   ├── views/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── imageview.py
│   │   ├── label.py
│   │   ├── mainview.py
│   │   ├── volumeview.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│
├── utils/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── progress_window.py
```

My problem is that this is meant to be later compiled and executed in a way that it allows me to create plugins as CScan is.

As of now, my approach to execute the application is running `python main.py` from inside the VisionPy directory. The current problem I am having is I can't manage to import NDEToolkit from *plugin.py* despite them being in the same folder. This is a problem, because I want to create a plugin interface with easy access even to people that does not know much about programing, and appending folders to system path does not seem like the best approach to achieve it.

Also, I want to be able to compile the project with [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) or some similar package and make it easy to just paste a folder into plugins that contains at least a *plugin.py* and a *[requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506852/what-is-the-requirements-txt-what-should-be-in-it)* file, which is how my interface works.

I don't know whether I really need all those ***init**.py* files, as I don't plan to make the whole thing a package, as it is a GUI application developed with PyQt 5 and *main.py* looks like this:

```
# main.py

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from controllers.imagecontroller import ImageController
from controllers.volumecontroller import VolumeController
from ui.views.mainview import MainView

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create the main view
    main_view = MainView()

    # Create the controllers and pass the main_view to them
    image_controller = ImageController(main_view)
    volume_controller = VolumeController(main_view)

    # Set controllers in the main view
    main_view.set_image_controller(image_controller)
    main_view.set_volume_controller(volume_controller)

    # Show the main view
    main_view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As musicamante pointed out, this is the code that is giving me problems, which is *VisionPy/plugins/CScan/plugin.py*:

```
from plugin_interface import PluginInterface
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from pathlib import Path
import traceback
import sys
import os
print(sys.path)

plugin_dir = str(Path(__file__).parent.resolve())
if plugin_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(plugin_dir)

import NDEToolkit as ndt
import numpy as np
import tifffile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plugin(PluginInterface):
.
.
.
```

The problem comes in the line `import NDEToolkit as ndt`, and as you can see, *NDEToolkit.py* is located in the same folder as *plugin.py*, which is the file I try to import it from.

I organized the project like this thinking about the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Comment: If the problem is in the `plugins.py`, then you need to show us the code for that script. This is an import problem and has nothing to do with PyQt. You probably tried to do a "global" import (without considering the relative package/directory paths and imports).

Comment: I do the following: `import NDEToolkit as ndt` I dont have access to the code right now, I will post it later

Comment: Have you tried using a relative import, e.g. `import .NDEToolkit as ndt` ?

Comment: I have and does not work anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to import from a subpackage. You need to either do an absolute import ([the preferred method](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)) or a relative import.

##### Absolute Import:

```
import plugins.CScan.NDEToolkit as ndt
```

##### Relative Import:

```
import .NDEToolkit as ndt
```

This is well documented in PEP 8 (linked above), other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/9403538) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/9403538), and [free online sources](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).